# Page templates in a sub-folder in theme from scratch in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I am building a theme from scratch and I want to have all my custom page templates and single post type templates in a sub folder (see below).

`-theme/
 - page.php
 - single.php
 -- templates/
 --- page-news.php
 --- single-report.php`

However, when I have moved `page-news.php` to this folder the "Default Template" does not pick up the template.

N.B. I am using **WordPress 4.6.1** and using a theme I've built from scratch.

Comment: Are you basing your structure off of the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)?

Comment: Yes I am @Frits

Comment: Cool - move the files inside your template folder, directly in to your theme folder. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep custom wordpress page templates in different folder other than the theme folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602079/how-to-keep-custom-wordpress-page-templates-in-different-folder-other-than-the-t)

Answer (score 2):

You can only define `templates` in the root of your themes. I generally manage all my partial templates as following:

```
 -Theme
 -- Templates Folder (partial templates etc.)
 --"news-template.php" file (I require/load all the templates I need here.)
```

This way you can keep all the `partial templates` in the template folder and structure them as you want. And load them into the `template` file in the root of the project.

I hope my explaination is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know WordPress will not automatically recognize any of your templates if you put them into a subfolder. I guess furthermore that there is not hook to fix this. However you can search the core and try to modify this.

What I recommend is the following: Do not use the WordPress auto detection of template files it is quite clumsy anyway. In your index.php file use conditional tags in order to route WordPress correctly.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

This way your are 10 times more flexible regarding subfolders as well as code: You do not need to copy/paste code within the template files.

Use

```
get_template_part(..)
```

within your routing functions.

I have built hundreds of WordPress sites and I always do it this way. It is also recommended in some WordPress books.

Note: The loading mechanism of WP is shown within the following image: https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png

**Update 2018:** It is possible to put page templates which are selectable in the post edit screen into a `/page-templates/` subfolder and they are detected automatically.

Comment: Is it possible to use a similar to technique to change the default location for the 404.php or single.php templates? I want my template root folder to just be home.php, index.php, and style.css. I want everything else in folders.

Comment: @DavidA.French Yes this is certainly possible. Just put your conditionals into index.php in order to decide. Also not that I updated my answer.

Comment: Is there a boilerplate for the index.php conditionals? By default I'm assuming that's handled by WP core, right?

Comment: By default: Yes. But if you do not create templates like single.php or page.php then as a default always index.php is loaded. You can even just use a single loop and do the conditionals only from within the loop. Also look my updated answer.